# GAE variance in performance, especially datastore reads

Tags: performance, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

We've seen an overall degradation in performance over, what seems like the last year or so, and also a degradation the first time a given user's data is accessed on a given day.

We've identified a specific datastore query, that often can return entities at a rate of about 50ms each, degrade to about 500ms:

```
users = User.get_by_id(usersToGet_IntArray)
```

Since it seems like the front end is mostly waiting on the server, it doesn't seem like a faster machine class would help. We're accessing the datastore natively, using Python. Any idea what we can do to consistently get performance on the better end of the range? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't know why, it looks like we found a super simple (magic) fix.  By setting

```
threadsafe = false
```

in app.yaml -- i.e. going back to running our handlers in single-threaded mode -- our average performance is now faster than the best case performance numbers we were seeing before (for the aforementioned query, entities getting returned in 12ms consistently).

And somehow, also, while the number of loading instances has doubled, the billable instances hasn't increased. So it looks like it's not going to increase cost.